# How can I extract elements of an array inside an array to this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I extract elements of an array inside an array to this array?

What I have is this:

```
const tableData = [
    {
        display: '2022-03',
        column: 'data',
        detailList: [
            {
                title: 'Quantity',
                value: 1,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Price',
                value: 2,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Weight',
                value: 3,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'income',
                value: 4,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            
        ],
    },
    {
        display: '2022-02',
        column: 'data',
        detailList: [
            {
                title: 'Quantity',
                value: 7,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Price',
                value: 6,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Weight',
                value: 5,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'income',
                value: 4,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            
        ],
    },
];
```

Now I want it to become this:

```
res = [
    {
        title: '2022-03',
        'Quantity': '1',
        'Price': '2',
        'Weight': '3',
        'income': '4',      
    },
    {
        title: '2022-02',
        'Quantity': '7',
        'Price': '6',
        'Weight': '5',
        'income': '4',
    },
];
```

What's the best way to do it?

I'm trying to create a new array outside, and use two `.map()` to make it. But it looks not readable.

Can somebody give me a better solution that uses some ES6 features that makes it look more readable.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post code as images. See [ask]. Put your code in a snippet demo using the editor.

Comment: Please try this: iterate over the `tableData` array (using `.map()`) and use `.reduce()` for the `detailList` array to return an object with the desired key-value pairs. Append this object with `title: ....`. That's it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the result of `map()` directly to `res`, rather than calling `push()` inside the map.

You can use `Object.fromEntries()` to create the object from the inner map.

Destructuring and spread syntax can simplify the way you access the properties and build the resulting object.

```js
const tableData = [{
    display: '2022-03',
    column: 'data',
    detailList: [{
        title: 'Quantity',
        value: 1,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Price',
        value: 2,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Weight',
        value: 3,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: 'income',
        value: 4,
        sourceId: null,
      },

    ],
  },
  {
    display: '2022-02',
    column: 'data',
    detailList: [{
        title: 'Quantity',
        value: 7,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Price',
        value: 6,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Weight',
        value: 5,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: 'income',
        value: 4,
        sourceId: null,
      },

    ],
  },
];

let res = tableData.map(({
  display,
  detailList
}) => ({
  title: display,
  ...Object.fromEntries(detailList.map(({
    title,
    value
  }) => [title, value === null ? '-' : value]))
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: It is my understanding that this answer is a better solution in terms of performance (since the one with the `.reduce()` uses `...` multiple times, among other potential reason/s).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const res = tableData.map(({ display, detailList}) => {
  const obj = {
    title: display,
  }
  detailList.forEach(el => obj[el.title] = el.value);
  return obj;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const transformArray = arr => arr.map(  // iterate using "map"
  ({display : title, detailList}) => ({ // de-structure, and rename
    title,
    ...(
      detailList.reduce(                // iterate using "reduce"
        (fin, {title, value}) => ({     // de-structure to access title, value
          ...fin,
          [title]: value                // may add "value" is null check here
        }),
        {}                              // the "fin" object is initialized to empty
      )
    )
  })
);

const tableData = [
    {
        display: '2022-03',
        column: 'data',
        detailList: [
            {
                title: 'Quantity',
                value: 1,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Price',
                value: 2,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Weight',
                value: 3,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'income',
                value: 4,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            
        ],
    },
    {
        display: '2022-02',
        column: 'data',
        detailList: [
            {
                title: 'Quantity',
                value: 7,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Price',
                value: 6,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'Weight',
                value: 5,
                sourceId: null,
            },
            {
                title: 'income',
                value: 4,
                sourceId: null,
            },
        ],
    },
];


console.log(transformArray(tableData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments explain the steps involved.

**NOTES**

This solution uses:

- '.map()`
- `.reduce()`
- de-structure and rename (`display` is renamed as `title`
- arrow functions
- `...` spread to perform shallow-copy

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const tableData = [
  {
    display: "2022-03",
    column: "data",
    detailList: [
      {
        title: "Quantity",
        value: 1,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: "Price",
        value: 2,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: "Weight",
        value: 3,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: "income",
        value: 4,
        sourceId: null,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    display: "2022-02",
    column: "data",
    detailList: [
      {
        title: "Quantity",
        value: 7,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: "Price",
        value: 6,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: "Weight",
        value: 5,
        sourceId: null,
      },
      {
        title: "income",
        value: 4,
        sourceId: null,
      },
    ],
  },
];
const res = [];
tableData.map((i) => {
  let obj;
  i.detailList.forEach((j) => {
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      [j.title]: j.value,
    };
  });
  res.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: The result of `i.detailList.map()` isn't being used, so it should be `forEach()`